# Comparison between DateField and date.today()

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a method inside a Django Model class for a Task, that must return the risk situation of such, based on the comparison of expected start and finish dates with today, but I get an error when I try to compare start_date and finish_date models.DateField with date.today()

this is the code of the method:

```
def get_todo_situation(self):
    if self.finish_date == None:
        return 'unassigned'
    elif date.today() < self.start_date:
        return 'warning'
    elif date.today() < self.finish_date:
        return 'danger'
    else:
        return 'normal'
```

and this is the error I get:

```
 File "/home/hugolvc/Code/TaskManagerProject/TaskManager/TaskManagerApp/models.py", line 63, in get_todo_situation
elif date.today() < self.start_date:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'NoneType'
```

I have seen examples where this works, but I think I am failing to grasp something.

Comment: This is telling you that the field is empty.

Comment: Is start_date or finish_date a datetime object or a string?

Comment: Your start_date doesn't have a value (ie. start_date is None)

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you. It worked